# copy filtered data in poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to copy rows from excel sheet which does  contain filter criteria. I am setting hidden property rows which unmatch with criteria.

```
 XSSFRow r1;
    for(Row r:my_sheet)
    {
        r1=my_sheet.getRow(i);
        for(Cell c:r)
        {

            c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            if ( (c.getColumnIndex()==0 && !list2.contains(c.getStringCellValue())) || (c.getColumnIndex()==1 && !list1.contains(c.getStringCellValue())) ) {
                r1 = (XSSFRow) c.getRow();
                if (r1.getRowNum() != 0) { /* Ignore top row */
                    /* Hide Row that does not meet Filter Criteria */
             r1.getCTRow().setHidden(true);

                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Please share the problem... What is wrong with this code? you just said that you want to do something... but not shared what is stopping you.

Comment: i am setting hidden property but when i am getting it returns true for all rows

Comment: Not able to understand your code completely. However my observation is 

For i = 0, j will start with 0... and for i = 1, j will start with 1
For the rest j will never be 0 or 1... so it will never reach to the if statement you have given.
and so rows will never hide.